# How to put values from json into inputs by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**In my React component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles/editIntern.sass";

const EditIntern = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [intern, setIntern] = useState([]);
  const [name, inputName] = useState("");
  const [email, inputEmail] = useState("");
  const [start, inputStart] = useState("");
  const [end, inputEnd] = useState("");

  const [errorNameEmpty, isErrorNameEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorEmailValid, iserrorEmailValid] = useState(false);
  const [errorStartEmpty, isErrorStartEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorEndEmpty, isErrorEndEmpty] = useState(false);

  const validEmail = new RegExp(
    /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/gm
  );

  const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let startDate = new Date(start).getTime();
    let endDate = new Date(end).getTime();

    if (startDate > endDate) {
      console.log("Start > end");
      console.log(startDate);
      console.log(endDate);
    } else {
      console.log("Ok");
      console.log(startDate);
      console.log(endDate);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIntern = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/interns/${id}`);
      const intern = await response.json();
      setIntern(intern);
    };
    fetchIntern();
    console.log(`I want to get intern with id: ${id}!`);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <img className="Logo" src="../logo.svg" alt="logo" />
      <section className="EditIntern">
        <NavLink to="/">
          <button className="EditIntern_back">
            <img
              className="EditIntern_back-img"
              src="../button_back_icon.svg"
              alt="button_back"
            />{" "}
            Back to list
          </button>
        </NavLink>
        <form className="EditIntern_form">
          <h4 className="EditIntern_form-title">Edit</h4>
          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_name">
            Full name *
          </label>
          <input
            className="EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (e.target.value === "") {
                isErrorNameEmpty(true);
              } else {
                isErrorNameEmpty(false);
              }
              inputName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorNameEmpty ? (
            <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_name">
              Name can't be empty
            </span>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_email">
            Email address *
          </label>
          <input
            className="EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_email"
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (e.target.value === "") {
                iserrorEmailValid(true);
              } else if (!validEmail.test(e.target.value)) {
                iserrorEmailValid(true);
              } else {
                iserrorEmailValid(false);
              }
              inputEmail(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorEmailValid ? (
            <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_email">
              Example: email@gmail.com
            </span>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_start">
            Internship start *
          </label>
          <input
            className="EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_start"
            type="date"
            name="email"
            value={start}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (!isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber))
                inputStart(e.target.valueAsNumber);
              if (e.target.value === "") {
                isErrorStartEmpty(true);
              } else {
                isErrorStartEmpty(false);
              }
            }}
          />
          {errorStartEmpty ? (
            <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_start">
              Start date can't be empty
            </span>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_end">
            Internship end *
          </label>
          <input
            className="EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_end"
            type="date"
            name="email"
            value={end}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (!isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber))
                inputEnd(e.target.valueAsNumber);
              if (e.target.value === "") {
                isErrorEndEmpty(true);
              } else {
                isErrorEndEmpty(false);
              }
            }}
          />
          {errorEndEmpty ? (
            <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_end">
              End date can't be empty
            </span>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <input
            className="EditIntern_form-submit"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            onClick={onFormSubmit}
          />
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditIntern;
```

**I need inputs to be filled with values from the intern array when this component is called (intern.name, intern.email ...) Now with useState the inputs are empty by default. I need by default with data from intern but with the ability to erase and fill in as you like.**

*As I already wrote, intern is an array with data that is rendered when this component is opened, it has all the data that needs to be placed by default.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem if i see correctly is in that you don't getting data from array intern you just getting it from name, email, etc.

So on start set that values like intern.name to name etc.

after that you could save it inside array using

`setIntern({name: name, ...intern})`

and contiue with that using other parametrs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not really the problem. I have access to intern.name, intern.email. I don't understand how to pass these values to the inputs so that when the component is rendered, the fields are filled with this data. The user, if necessary, will erase what is displayed in the inputs by default (for example, intern.name), and write what he needs.

Comment: Just in update function (useEffect) do setName(intern.name), setEmail(intern.email) ?

Comment: Oh i see that you named as inputName so you should use that instead of setName

Comment: Perhaps you know how to display the date? In json, it is stored in the following format - "2021-07-01T00:00+00Z". My input[type = date] doesn't understand this value

Comment: Date format is only Year:month:day and then there is time that is the time you don't want so get rid of it using `"2021-07-01T00:00+00Z".slice(0,10)`